# Fading slideshow not cycling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make a fading slideshow only I cant seem to get it to fade...

http://jsfiddle.net/FGb6L/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you change

```
$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

into

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000 );
});
```

the slideshow seems to work. Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eSrcr/

as a side note, [never pass strings to setInterval/setTimeout](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=2#timeouts)